# Counting method calls in controller using c# in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project where it would be very helpful to be able to count the number of times a method is called (or `ActionResult` being returned). However, a simple counter does not work using the following code:

```
namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

        int counter = 0;

        public ActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            counter++;

            // Do more

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to count this? I couldn't find anything about this subject using Google or searching here on SO, so I assume the way I phrased it or the way I tried implementing this is not correct, maybe someone could elaborate on the code above and explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you _really_ just want a counter, or is this an XY problem where you are trying to reinvent application monitoring?

Comment: Why do you want to count it? What problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to count it because that is the easiest way I can think of to compare the amount of times a certain is called against a variable, which I can then use to display / not display buttons on my website.

Comment: _"compare the amount of times a certain [action method] is called"_ - now we're getting somewhere, but you still haven't explained enough of the problem for a proper solution. Does this variable count for all users, or do you want to show/hide the buttons for one user depending on how many times that user called that method? How long-lived is the counter, should the value be persisted between appdomain recycles? Should it again be stored per-user, or per-application?

Comment: Well one option is to take counter as static whenever your method is called from any client it will be incremented.
Other way is to store counter in database and increment it each time your method is called. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @CodeCaster To go a bit more in-depth: I'm showing exhibitions on my website, which can be filtered per year. So when clicking on a button 'Read more', a method in the controller is called to return the exhibitions being showed. I made a method to see the total count of exhibitions, and I want to compare this to the amount of times this method is being called, so I can set a variable in my model which is a boolean, which I use in my page view to display / not display a button.

Comment: Making the count variable static actually solved the problem, so I will accept @JesseJames' answer in 2 mins.

Comment: The static variable will count for all users. Don't use that solution as it'll break your site when you get more than one visitor (test it with two browsers). Rewrite your question and include actual, relevant code so people can come up with a proper solution.

Comment: Hmm, alright, then I'm still searching for a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter you're implementing works in memory. If application restarts the counter will be reset.

The `counter` variable must be static, so it will work until your application pool is not restarted. It also must be thread save.

You must lock a shared object (it also may be a static variable) before incrementing counter.

```
namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

        static int counter = 0;
        static object lockObj = new object();
        public ActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            lock(lockObj)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            // Do more

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to have counter for each user you may use `Session` state.

```
if(Session["counterKey"] != null)
{
    int counter = (int)Session["counterKey"];
    counter++;
    Session["counterKey"] = counter;
}
else
{
    Session["counterKey"] = 1; // first call
}
```

Comment: I will try implementing the `Session` state now, hopefully that will work.

Comment: In mvc every time an http request is being made to a controller,the mvc framework is creating a new instance of the controller.So in your code,each call creates a new counter variable and sets it's value to 0!The static approach is one solution that could work.FYI You could also use a file or a database table.